# Solr Connection' already registered in container

Tags: asp.net, solrnet

i am using solr search on asp.net

when i search first time it give me correct search result, bt after that when i change search parameter and try to search it give an error 
                  ("Solr Connection' already registered in container")

so pl z suggest me that how can i remove it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure that you are only initializing the connection to the Solr instance once, by putting something similar to the following in the `Application_Start` event in the *Global.asax.<language>* file.

```cs
Startup.Init<Product>("http://localhost:8983/solr");
```

Can you post a code snippet of how you are opening the `SolrConnection` and querying against the Solr instance? What version of the SolrNet library are you using?

I am using SolrNet version 0.2.3 in an ASP.NET application using the convention described above.

Answer (score 6):

My solution is to clear `Startup` before `Init`.

```cs
Startup.Container.Clear();
Startup.InitContainer();
Startup.Init<T>("http://localhost:8983/solr/test");
```